# Integrating custom view into my app

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-custom-view

I am building my app and I require a seek arc in my layout for it. I used the seekarc view from the opensource github project https://github.com/TriggerTrap/SeekArc. I have almost finished merging this into my app, but I got stuck when I defined the seekarc code in the layout xml. My xml code is like this :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.test.MainActivity" >

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Switch On"
    android:id = "@+id/onbtn"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

 <com.triggertrap.seekarc.SeekArc
    android:id="@+id/seekArc"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:padding="30dp"
    seekarc:rotation="180"
    seekarc:startAngle="30"
    seekarc:sweepAngle="300"
    seekarc:touchInside="true" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

While merging, I have defined a new package com.triggertrap.seekarc wherein I have put the SeekArc.java file defined in the github project. I get an error saying

```
error: Error parsing XML: unbound prefix
```

on the seekarc view in this xml. Please let me know what further changes I should make so that there are no errors w.r.t this. I have already integrated all related attribute xmls and drawables into the appropriate folders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:seekarc="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.test.MainActivity" >

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Switch On"
    android:id = "@+id/onbtn"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

 <com.triggertrap.seekarc.SeekArc
    android:id="@+id/seekArc"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:padding="30dp"
    seekarc:rotation="180"
    seekarc:startAngle="30"
    seekarc:sweepAngle="300"
    seekarc:touchInside="true" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

You are missing to define  `xmlns:seekarc="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"`

Comment: Thank you so much. Now that error has vanished. Please let me know the purpose and meaning of that line so that I can understand it.

Comment: Please go through this http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/create-view.html#customattr